# Does Django have method to 'validate' form fields BEFORE form submission?

Tags: django, validation

I have read Django documentation and found almost 2 ways to validate fields forms (clean_data, validators) but I am looking for a method to test fields **before** form submission

i can do it with JS but I wonder if there is a way to do it with Django

Comment: before form submission, that sound like operation that should be in the frontend

Comment: Hello Slater, and welcome :-) The first bulb I see is to validate each field as its filled, one by one. But then even though validation would be server-side, you'd still need js to send the background calls for each field validation. Hope it's of some use :-)

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done before submission - how the server would now what user put into each field? It can only validate the data when it gets it - after user submits a form.